# how to e-mail filtered data

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have checked a few other questions that have had this issue and I cant see where i have gone wrong if someone could help me. I have a macro `Reported` that filters out data that I don't need to pass on. The rest should then be selected and e-mailed out. The issue is that the corresponding data is e-mailed as blank.

```
Sub SendCONSULTANT()
    Reported
    Dim OLApp           As OUTLOOK.Application
    Dim OLMail          As Object
    Dim sFileName       As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim todaydate As String


    name = Sheets("Accepting List").Range("b8").Value
    todaydate = Format(CStr(Now), "DDDD D MMMM YYYY")
    sFileName = "\" & "Outstanding Cases " & todaydate & _
    ".xlsx"

    Set OLApp = New OUTLOOK.Application
    Set OLMail = OLApp.CreateItem(0)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("B6:n68").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Workbooks.Add

    With Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & sFileName

    OLApp.Session.Logon

    With OLMail
        .To = "******@*****.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Outstanding CT Cases"
        .Body = "Hello" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please find attached an extract of all outstanding cases that may require reporting" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind Regards" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        .Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.Path & sFileName)
        .Display
        .Send
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & sFileName

    Set OLMail = Nothing
    Set OLApp = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Reportedrestore
End Sub
```

If anyone can tell me why the visible cell selection isn't working I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your changes are saved to the file you may try to open on the disk observe the file content.

The [Workbooks.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.add) method creates a new workbook, a `Workbook` object that represents the new workbook is returned back. So, I'd suggest using this ibject for pasting the data and saving to the disk.